# Как правильно выстроить логику сравнения чисел с объекта? js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть массив объектов, в котором есть числа и например текст, пример такого массива:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    val: 10,
    text: 'dsadas'
  },
  {
    val: 20,
    text: 'sdfsds'
  },
  {
    val: 30,
    text: 'sssss'
  }
];

var startText  = 'asdas',
    finishText = 'asdasdasda';
```

Есть входящее число, надо его обработать, проверить: если число имеет значение 0 - вывести `startText`, если больше последнего числа в массиве - вывести `finishText` , если находится в пределах между `val` объектов - выводить `text` с данного объекта. Хочется именно правильно сделать, без огромного количества `if` и с учетом что может меняться количество объектов в массиве. Помогите пожалуйста, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей уже

Comment: А вам будет трудно составить примерно вот такой массив? `arr[10->fdsfsdf, 20->sfdsfdsf]` то есть что бы число было `key` массива а текст значение (value). а потом просто посмотреть есть ли значение с входящим числом, и сразу взять его, если нет то ваша логина на счет `start` и `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [{
    val: 10,
    text: 'dsadas'
  },
  {
    val: 20,
    text: 'sdfsds'
  },
  {
    val: 30,
    text: 'sssss'
}];
const startText  = 'start';
const finishText = 'finish';

// Для удобства добавим граничные значения в начало и конец массива.
arr.push({
   val: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
   text: finishText
});
arr.unshift({
   val: 0,
   text: startText
});

// теперь найти нужный диапазон крайне просто.
input.onchange = () => {
  const number = input.value;
  const el = arr.find(el => number <= el.val);
  console.log(el);
}
```

```html
<input id='input' />
```

Единственный минус - если массив будет не отсортирован, работать не будет.

Comment: не правильно работает, дал число 40 мне выдало текст который соответствует 30-и.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ок ща переставлю =

Comment: Опять одно и то же

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я просто неправильно вопрос понял. Так еще проще.

Comment: Уже работает нормально

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое, очень выручили